# How to visualize results of LDA topic modelling as shown below

Tags: matplotlib, plotly, seaborn, gensim, lda

As a part of the assignment, I am asked to do topic modeling using LDA and visualize the words that come under the top 3 topics as shown in the below screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4Buq.png). However, even after searching a lot I am not able to find any helpful resource that would help me achieve my goal. All resources about text visualization are pointed towards the word cloud, but my goal is not to use word cloud visualizations.
[Required LDA topic visulization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4Buq.png)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you use gensim to generate the LDA model (`gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel()`) you can use the following to easily visualize the key words related to each topic:

```
# Example of LDA model building: 
lda_model = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus,
                                           id2word=id2word,
                                           num_topics=20, 
                                           random_state=100,
                                           update_every=1,
                                           chunksize=100,
                                           passes=10,
                                           alpha='auto',
                                           per_word_topics=True)
# Visualize keywords
print(lda_model.print_topics())
```

Also for better visualization I suggest you to use pyLDAvis through:

```
import pyLDAvis
import pyLDAvis.gensim 
pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()
vis = pyLDAvis.gensim.prepare(lda_model, corpus, id2word)
vis
```

Where you feed your lda model, corpus and a **dictionary** mapping ids to tokens (`id2word`). Output:

[image]

Have a look at the example here for a detailed explanation: 
https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/topic-modeling-gensim-python/